# htaccess transparent redirect becomes a 301 instead

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to do a transparent redirect of http://example.com/a/b?passcode=hello&go=rate to http://example.com/a/b/q?passcode=hello

'a' is always the same, whereas 'b' keeps on changing

This is the .htaccess i am using in my root folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} passcode=(.*)&go=rate
RewriteRule ^a(.*)?$ /a$1/q?passcode=%1 [L]
```

This doesn't work as expected - I get 301 Moved Permanently when I run http://example.com/a/b?passcode=hello&go=rate

If I go on to change the RewriteRule to

```
RewriteRule ^a(.*)?$ /a$1/q?passcode=%1 [L,R]
```

it works as expected and does a 301 redirect to http://example.com/a/b/q?passcode=hello.

However, how do I make it work with a transparent redirect? 
I am new to this so all comments are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (passcode=[^&]+)&go=rate [NC]
RewriteRule ^(a/[^/]+)/?$ /$1/q?%1 [L,NC]
```

Make sue there is no .htaccess in `/a/` folder.

Comment: Still have the same issue. In my network, it shows as 301 Moved Permanently and it doesnt direct to http://example.com/a/b/q?passcode=hello

I checked and it is the only .htaccess file which resides on the server

Comment: What is the URL you're entering in browser? Test it in a different browser to avoid old caching. Also if you have other rules post them here.

Comment: This is the only rule I have. I was entering http://example.com/a/b?passcode=hello&go=rate earlier. I just now tried using http://example.com/a/b/?passcode=hello&go=rate [notice the forward slash] and does a permanent 301 redirect to http://example.com/a/b/q?passcode=hello. Using your htaccess rule at the moment and cache is disabled

Comment: 1. There is no 301 redirect in the rule shown. 2. If you entered `http://example.com/a/b/?passcode=hello&go=rate` with a trailing slash then there is no trailing slash being added for directory either.

Comment: Yes, most likely it is being 301 redirected because of some other rule. I know there is no .htaccess else on the server. Can it because of something in httpd.conf? Thanks

Comment: Yes `httpd.conf` can also have rewrite rules.